# Partition became RAW after accessing with Linux

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, multi-boot

I have a portable hard disk drive that is split into 2 NTFS partitions. For some reason, when I booted Linux (Ubuntu) to clean a locked virus on each partition, mounting was fine, and the virus was deleted. I tried booting to Windows XP afterwards, and what I found was that one of partitions became RAW, and I need the data on it.

For now I haven't touched the RAW partition. The other partition works fine.

Can someone suggest a way to recover the partition or the data inside it? Freeware/open-source solutions are preferred.

**Edit:**
Strangely enough, I tried to read the portable HDD on Windows 2003 Server, and it recognized the partition, but not with XP. I will backup all files before trying to fix the boot sector.

Comment: What did you use to mount the partitions? Did you unmount the drives when you were done?

Comment: i use Ubuntu (gnome desktop) file manager, double click on portable hdd drive and it mount automatically (linux end user, not an advance user), i did unmount before shut down

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to recover your data with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). It's available in ubuntu repositories.

Comment: tested the windows version, but i don't understand how it works to recover partition? i can access the partition and view the file list and what next?

Comment: They are tons of tutorials on the website i linked to ... here is one of them: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Answer (score -1):

Not positive if this would work but could you use the Windows command prompt convert command to convert it to the NTFS file system?  I know this works between FAT, FAT32, and NTFS, but with RAW, couldn't hurt to try after you backup what you can access

Comment: I'd first try to change the partition type with e.g. `fdisk`