# My external HD turned to RAW - How to recover my data?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, external-hard-drive, sata

I have an external HD (WD MyBook Essentials) with all of my backups (1TB)
for some unknown reason, when I try to connect the drive (Tried several interfaces: eSATA/plugged it into my PC/USB)
I get this message:

> "You need to format the disk in drive M: before you can use it"

I've looked in disk management at the drive, and its listed in there - with the same full capacity.
The file system under disk management now says RAW and that its healthy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partition became RAW after accessing with Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/64874/partition-became-raw-after-accessing-with-linux)

Comment: If you can recall, what was the file system on that drive.. Was the drive formatted with NTFS or FAT32?? ..

Answer (score 1):

If this is a problem of lost partitions, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is worth a try.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, but Iv'e kinda tried that software.
I don't know how to use it actually...

Comment: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step step by step guide to testdisk

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the drive with a Linux LiveCD and NTFS3G- sometimes it manages to open “lost” NTFS drives. If that fails then I’d suggest using TestDisk as [mouviciel suggested in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/344963/167207).

Comment: I'm in a process of downloading Knoppix.
It should do the trick as well?

Comment: as long as it has NTFS 3g. I tend to use ubuntu live since i usually have some flavour of it lying around