# How can I restore a partition to its former NTFS file system?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, swap, hard-drive-recovery

While installing Ubuntu 11.04 I was asked to choose a swap area for better performances,
so I chose my 1T hard drive(which had only one partition).

The problem is that I did not know it will use the partition as swap area rather than just put a swap file in the selected partition... (there was an unmarked "format" check box so I assume that my data will be saved)

This hard drive holds all my program files etc so I want it back!

So far I did:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

What can I do in order to make my hard drive come back with its data? I do not wish to retrieve only selected files with some recovery tools.

P.S: it was 5-10% used before the accident and I immediately invoked the swapoff so I hope that my data was untouched.

Answer (score 0):

As I just [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/344947/my-external-hd-turned-to-raw-how-to-recover-my-data/344963#344963) to another question, if the damage is only a lost partition, you can check [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: I read your answer, however it does not suit my problem. while running TestDisk it finds the "Linux swap" partition.
I want to get my previous partition back.
Do you know of any way to solve this? (maybe i am using the TestDisk wrong...?)