# Puzzled whether format the partition or simply copy back contents

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, multi-boot, memory-management

In my previous question [ntfs-partition-gets-auto-corrupt-becomes-raw-and-unreadable](https://superuser.com/questions/361575/ntfs-partition-gets-auto-corrupt-becomes-raw-and-unreadable),
 I got some answers, but I am still not clear as to how to solve the problem.
To quickly summarize it,

**Problem:** NTFS partition goes corrupt
**OS present:** Dual boot (Win8 and Ubuntu 11)
**Partition type:** Physical, but not bootable, win8 installation and ubuntu hv their separate partitions

So, far
I have a dd backup of the whole partition `/dev/sda2` on my other Portable Disk as a file `backup.img`.

I tried [testdisk repair NTFS partition](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_NTFS_Boot_and_MFT_Repair#Repair_An_NTFS_MFT) but got this error

> Both MFT and MFTMirr are damaged and thus cannot be repaired using TestDisk

NOTE: I even can't get to `chkdsk /f` for the given corrupt partition because I can't open a command prompt for that location.

Is there a way that I can simply format the drive in Windows and then get the data back from the .img backup???

My topmost priority is to get my data back as it was (same folders and sub-folders, without the hazzle of creating them again), as most of it is my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the .img file with [MagicIso](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-features.htm) or [Unviersal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract). That gets you back your data.

Comment: Universal Extractor gives the following error: `Extract NT - Extract file in wImage - V 2.10 (c) 1991-96 Gilles Vollant
Visit web page : http://ourworld.compuserve.com/homepages/gvollant/extract.htm
image file : G:\backup-sda2.img  this file is not a disk image`

Comment: and the link says that Compuserve is shut down.

Comment: Could it be that you have a bad image? i.e. you imaged a bad drive, and therefore its a bad image?

Comment: MagicISO unregistered version can only open images upto 300MB, where as mine's size is 150GB, because it's a whole partition.

Comment: Could be so, I have a link to my previous question in the question at the begining, can you have a look there...

Comment: No idea really, sorry.